# Does the question belong in Mathematics?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I wrote a program that computes the fast **insert_name_here** transform of a matrix. I am at a loss of what its application is, what its proper name should be, and find an existing algorithm for it. I posted this question in Computer Science, and one of their members suggested it might be better served here. Does this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51446/what-can-i-do-with-this-algorithm) belong in Mathematics? Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you did something without knowing why you did it, or maybe you did it for no reason, and you want someone to tell you that what you did is useful?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I did something I knew was possible and true. I never knew what its application is or if it already exists.

Comment: Lots of things are possible, but you apparently haven't given any indication of why you did this particular thing, and you still seem to want someone to tell you that it's useful. So, in my opinion, your question is not a good one, but may be suitable for this site.

Comment: @AntonioVargas My first hypothesis was it might be useful in reducing the amount of information needed to perform a partial reconstruction of a matrix's eigenvalues.

Comment: Post it, worst case someone says its not appropriate and then you know. On the flip side, maybe you have done some cool math which warrants an interesting answer, or at least connects your ideas in a nontrivial way to some applications. I don't think one needs to have a reason to do math, although it certainly helps a lot.

Comment: What is the actual question? Is the question "What can I do with this?" If so, probably not a suitable question. If it is "Where/how can't I get published?" that might be more suitable on the academia stackexchange. I haven't heard you suggest you have a math problem yet...